# Lock partitioning deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have a table with around 3.5 million rows. Lock partitioning [1] is enabled on the database. The table gets a lot of inserts during the day, and I'm getting a lot of deadlocks on lock partitions. These types of deadlocks are described nicely at http://sqlindian.com/2012/07/07/deadlocks-involving-lock-partitions/ but there the author says that these types of deadlocks are extremely rare. In our case they don't seem rare at all!

I could disable lock partitioning with trace flag 1229, but that's not recommended. Does anyone have some advice about how to avoid these types of deadlocks, or how I could analyze the situation further to see why we are getting so many of these "rare" type of deadlocks?

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187504(v=sql.105).aspx

UPDATE: Add example deadlock graph

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process5004748" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process5004748" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 5:1423344135:0 " waittime="3008" ownerId="2379819613" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-03-14T09:28:55.803" XDES="0x77ab8f950" lockMode="X" schedulerid="11" kpid="5416" status="suspended" spid="507" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2013-03-14T09:28:55.817" lastbatchcompleted="2013-03-14T09:28:55.807" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="ExampleHost" hostpid="8664" loginname="ExampleUser" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="2379819613" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="" line="1" stmtstart="616" stmtend="1504" sqlhandle="0x020000002468011b993c824e2e0ce3fd2783a30e8e591641" />
        <frame procname="" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p0 datetime,@p1 bigint ...) INSERT INTO tblExample (Column1, Column2, ...); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()   
      </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="processd4a988" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 5:1423344135:10 " waittime="3008" ownerId="2379819595" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-03-14T09:28:55.663" XDES="0x2fe4323b0" lockMode="X" schedulerid="2" kpid="6756" status="suspended" spid="473" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2013-03-14T09:28:55.677" lastbatchcompleted="2013-03-14T09:28:55.667" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="ExampleHost" hostpid="8664" loginname="ExampleUser" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="2379819595" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="" line="1" stmtstart="616" stmtend="1504" sqlhandle="0x020000002468011b993c824e2e0ce3fd2783a30e8e591641" />
        <frame procname="" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
        (@p0 datetime,@p1 bigint ...) INSERT INTO tblExample (Column1, Column2, ...); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
      </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1423344135" subresource="FULL" dbid="5" objectname="" id="lock5d745ae00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="1423344135">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processd4a988" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process5004748" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </objectlock>
    <objectlock lockPartition="10" objid="1423344135" subresource="FULL" dbid="5" objectname="" id="lock55da8ea00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="1423344135">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process5004748" mode="IX" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processd4a988" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </objectlock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

UPDATE 2: Adding INSERT generated by NHibernate

```
begin transaction with isolation level: ReadUncommitted

INSERT INTO tblExample
            (Column1,
             Column2,
             Column2,
             Column3,
             Column4,
             Column5,
             Column6,
             Column7,
             Column8,
             Column9,
             Column10,
             Column11,
             Column12,
             Column13,
             Column14,
             Column15,
             Column16,
             Column17,
             Column18,
             Column19,
             Column20,
             Column21)
VALUES      ('2013-03-14T12:47:26.00' /* @p0 */,
             NULL /* @p1 */,
             75 /* @p2 */,
             'Test Text with some characters' /* @p3 */,
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22' /* @p4 */,
             2130706433 /* @p5 */,
             NULL /* @p6 */,
             NULL /* @p7 */,
             0 /* @p8 */,
             'Test Title' /* @p9 */,
             '11223344' /* @p10 */,
             0 /* @p11 */,
             '2013-03-14T12:47:26.00' /* @p12 */,
             0 /* @p13 */,
             '2013-03-14T12:47:26.00' /* @p14 */,
             'en' /* @p15 */,
             '2013-03-14T12:47:26.00' /* @p16 */,
             0 /* @p17 */,
             'SomeName' /* @p18 */,
             NULL /* @p19 */,
             917278 /* @p20 */,
             2805683 /* @p21 */);



select SCOPE_IDENTITY()

commit transaction
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumming due diligence (ie. you did the investigation correctly), and lets make it clear we're talking about [lock partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187504.aspx), not [partition locking](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sql-server-2008-partition-level-lock-escalation-details-and-examples/).

Unfortunately there is nothing you can do but make sure you are running the latest SP and latest CU. Preferably on latest product version. There were many fixes in this area. *If* you apply the latest SP and latest CU for the SP and the problem persists, contact product support.

> I could disable lock partitioning with trace flag 1229, but that's not recommended

How many cores do you have? You can always try and test.

Comment: Yes, am definitely talking about lock partitioning. Our deadlock graph fits all the critera in the referenced article, the locked objects are of the form OBJECT 5:2342545:23, there's a lockPartition="n", subresource="FULL" etc. I've added an example deadlock graph to the original post, in case you can get some extra information from that.

Comment: I might try disabling lock partitioning. The MSDN article says that it's enabled for 16 CPU servers. I guess there are plenty of people with servers with less than 16 cores, and they must be able to run pretty efficiently, so it can't be THAT bad to turn it off I guess...

Comment: Why does your INSERT require 'X' lock on the object? IX should be sufficient. Solve this puzzle and you solved your problem.

Comment: Hmmmm, good question. So, an IX lock should be enough for an insert, but I'm taking an X lock. Is there a hint or something I could give with my INSERT to tell it to not take an X lock? Couple of things I thought of: 1. We use NHibernate, not sure if that matters. 2. We use READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level. Again, not sure if it matters. (And thanks, really good to get some advice on this)

Comment: Can you post the exact INSERT statement generated by NHibernate?

Comment: READ UNCOMMITTED id [bad](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx) on its own, but should not contribute to your problem.

Comment: I've added the INSERT statement as I can see it in the NHibernate profiler. It looks pretty innocent, there are no explicit locking hints or anything.

Comment: Tangential comment: [LogParser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx) is awesome at shreding access logs, including upload into tables.

Comment: Can you check with SQL Profiler what does SQL actually see?

Comment: Finally got time to look at this again. The SQL Profiler basically sees INSERT INTO tblExample (Column1,...Column21 ) VALUES (@p0, ..., @p21); 

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); . All values are parameterized, ends with select scope identity. So, pretty plain SQL.

Answer (score 2):

We had similar issues and after proper investigation, found that the main problem were some indexes created without row_lock and page_lock enabled. So any insert,update,delete operation afecting that indexes generated a X lock at table level. Concurrent operations ended as deadlocks.

```
SELECT name indexname,allow_row_locks,allow_page_locks
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE 1=1 
--and object_id = object_id('tablename') 
AND allow_row_locks = 0 
AND allow_page_locks = 0
```

Comment: I'd +100 if I could ;) This actually save us from awful deadlocks in production today, after accidentaly recreating some indices with row and page locks off.